# How to pad with trailing zeroes when datetime formatting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    pta         ptd         tpl_num
4   05:17       05:18       0
6   05:29:30    05:30       1
9   05:42       05:44:30    2
11  05:53       05:54       3
12  06:03       06:05:30    4
```

I'm trying to format `pta` and `ptd` to `%H:%M:%S` using this:

```
df['pta'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['pta'], format="%H:%M:%S")
df['ptd'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['ptd'], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

This gives:

```
ValueError: time data '05:17' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

Makes sense, as some of my timestamps don't have `:00` in the seconds column. Is there any way to pad these at the end? Or will I need to pad my input data manually/before adding it to the DataFrame? I've seen plenty of answers that pad leading zeroes, but couldn't find one for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some dates do not match the specified format and hence are not correctly parsed. Let pandas parse them for you, and then use `dt.strftime` to format them as you want:

```
df['pta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['pta']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
df['ptd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ptd']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print(df)

       pta       ptd      tpl_num
4   05:17:00  05:18:00        0
6   05:29:30  05:30:00        1
9   05:42:00  05:44:30        2
11  05:53:00  05:54:00        3
12  06:03:00  06:05:30        4
```

Comment: I need the columns in datetime and not as strings, doesn't `strftime` return a string?

Comment: Actually my bad. You don't need `strfime` at all, since by default the seconds will go to `:00` @eddiewastaken So just let pandas infer the format for you

Comment: When I do this, it adds a date (current date actually) at the start.

Comment: Yes, pandas' datetime object will add all these for you. If you want a specific format as the one you use in your post you'll need to cast the columns to string @eddiewastaken You cannot have a datetime object without date

Comment: This is a nice suggestion @ALollz . Though IMO doesn't seem OP is interested in performing datetime operations since it doesn't really make since without a date. So I'm guessing this is not an intermediate step

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the padded strings, you can do:

```
df['pta'].add(':00').str[:8]
```

Output:

```
4     05:17:00
6     05:29:30
9     05:42:00
11    05:53:00
12    06:03:00
Name: pta, dtype: object
```

Also, for time only, you should consider using `pd.to_timedelta` instead of `pd.to_datetime`.